# Why a method with yield never execute?

Tags: c#, yield

Why a method with yield never execute? The Debug.Log o first call method never is reached!

```
public IEnumerator call(string method,WWWForm postData,Action<string> callback) {

    Debug.Log("call");

    WWW www = new WWW(this.apiUrl + method,postData);

    yield return www;

    Debug.Log("www ok");

    callback(www.text);


}

public IEnumerator call2(string method,WWWForm postData,Action<string> callback) {

    Debug.Log("call2");
    return null;

}

public void login(string email,string password,Action<string> callback)
{
    Debug.Log("login");

    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddField("email",email);
    form.AddField("password",password);

    Debug.Log("->playerLogin");

    this.call2("playerLogin", form,callback);
    this.call("playerLogin", form,callback);

    Debug.Log("<-playerLogin");

}
```

Comment: You never iterate the `IEnumerator` returned by `call` so the code is not run.

Comment: Answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13424485/lines-of-code-are-not-executed-after-calling-method-containing-yield covers when iterators are executed (question is a bit different asking about why some code never runs, but answer cover both).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yield is executed lazily. This means it will only execute when it is actually needed, when iterating:

```
var enumerable = this.call("playerLogin", form,callback);
enumerable.GetEnumerator().MoveNext(); // will be executed here
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not accessing the Enumerator returned by call (), so the yield method gets not executed.